# How to compile .cpp to a valid .cgi?

Tags: c++, apache, web, cgi

Below is my `test.cpp` file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   cout << "Content-type:text/html" << endl << endl;
   cout << "<html>" << endl;
   cout << "<head>" << endl;
   cout << "<title>Hello World - First CGI Program</title>" << endl;
   cout << "</head>" << endl;
   cout << "<body>" << endl;
   cout << "<h2>Hello World! This is my first CGI program</h2>" << endl;
   cout << "</body>" << endl;
   cout << "</html>" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Below is how I compiled the `test.cpp` file to `test.cgi` file.

```
g++ -g test.cpp -o test.cgi
```

Below is how I change mode of the `test.cgi` file.

```
chmod 755 test.cgi
```

There is no error at all.

But when I visit the page in the browser "localhost:8080/test.cgi", I get the following error:

```
C:/xampp/cgi-bin/test.cgi is not executable; ensure interpreted scripts have "#!" or "'!" first line
[cgi:error] [pid 22568:tid 1864] (9)Bad file descriptor: [client ::1:60380] AH01222: don't know how to spawn child process: C:/xampp/cgi-bin/test.cgi
```

The default `cgi.cgi` of Apache server works as well. It seems like the `test.cgi` file is invalid. Because I cannot even view the content of the file in Visual Studio Code, while I can view the content of the `cgi.cgi` file as well, the default file of Apache server.

When I run the following command line in the terminal, the content of the `test.cgi` file is printed successfully.

```
 ./test.cgi
```

How to create a valid `cgi` file from a `cpp` file?

Comment: Windows doesn't have an executable bit. It doesn't have chmod. Or g++. Are you using cygwin or something like that?

Comment: I am using sub linux system on windows. I also have tried the above steps on linux debian OS.

Comment: It seems like Apache is not the Linux subsystem version of Apache, so it doesn't know about all this Linux subsystem stuff. So it doesn't know the mode is 0755. It is probably expecting an executable file to end with .exe and be a Windows program (not Linux) because that is normal for Windows.

Comment: But the default `C:\xampp\cgi-bin\cgi.cgi` file works as well in the browser.

Comment: Of course, so I thought I must compile the `.cpp` file into that kind of `.cgi` file which contain the `#!` file

Comment: @OConner there is no such thing as a .cgi file. By Linux conventions it is just a file. `#!` means that this file is a program written in an interpreted language which should be interpreted by an interpreter.